# JAX-WS WSDL seems odd

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have create a JAX-WS web service using Netbeans, it's build successfully, and worked when I tested it with SOAPUI, but why this WSDL from JAX-WS is not very similar to "ordinary" wsdl I've seen on the internet.

For example `definition` tag, in ordinary wsdl the definition tag is `<wsdl:definition>` but in jax-ws wsdl it's just `<definition>` without wsdl word.

what happen? 
and how to make the jax-ws generates an ordinary wsdl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the namespace of wsdl. If the namespace has a local-name like `xmlns:wsdl="WSDL namespace value"` then you will have to to use the **`wsdl:definition`** in the xml file. If the default namespace for the XML document is defined such that `xmlns="WSDL namespace value"`, then it is sufficient to day **`definition`**.

Here is a quick doc on [understanding namespaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course).

Comment: oh thanks, but actually I have problems with wso2 ESB when the esb read the wsdl from jax-ws, EOF exception happened. do you have an experience in WSO2 ESB ?

Comment: That should be a different question. Post it as new question with appropriate tags and you will get a quick response that way.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please accept the answer.